# Sign a GitLab repository with an encryption key

Tags: git, encryption, gitlab

I am building a process with Docker, GitLab, and when pushing code to a GitLab repository, I want to send an encrypted key along with the code so that it uniquely identifies who I am. Then, I want another process that should be able to fetch, decrypt and identify who pushed the code and be able to do stuff with the code based on the identification to see what permissions the process that pushed the code has.

How can I build up the part where I sign a part of the repository with an encrypted key when pushing the repository to later on see the repository and identify through the key to be able to build and execute the code?

The flow should look like this: Log in to GitLab --> Sign a part of the repository with an encrypted key --> push the repository --> another user (admin) logs into GitLab --> logs in and sees the repository, identify who pushed the code through the key --> be able to build and execute the code

Comment: Like [this](https://docs.github.com/de/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sigstore](https://www.sigstore.dev/) for that.

[image: workflow]

From the documentation:

- Sign software artifacts with [Cosign](https://docs.sigstore.dev/cosign/overview/) — [Quick start](https://docs.sigstore.dev/cosign/overview/#getting-started-quick-start)
- Sign Git commits with [Gitsign](https://docs.sigstore.dev/gitsign/overview/) - [Quick start](https://Quick%20start)
- Verify entries with [Rekor](https://docs.sigstore.dev/rekor/CLI/#verify-proof-of-entry)
- Use the [policy controller](https://docs.sigstore.dev/policy-controller/overview/) to enfore Kubernetes policies
- Use the [Fulcio Certificate Authority](https://docs.sigstore.dev/fulcio/overview/)

More with "[Software Supply Chain Security](https://twit.tv/shows/floss-weekly/episodes/712?autostart=false)" with [Dan Lorenc](https://twitter.com/lorenc_dan),  Founder/CEO at http://chainguard.dev:

> So the SIG store project is a set of open source projects and some also some infrastructure, which makes it a little unique.
>
> But but the overall goal of all of this is to make code signing really, really easy and free for open source maintainers, if you're familiar with, which what Let's Encrypt did for TLS across the internet.
> That's kind of the same approach we're trying to take with Sigstore, except for code signing rather than TLS and HTTPS certificates.
>
> The infrastructure allows you to request these short-lived certificates that are only good for a couple minutes to use to sign your code.
> You authenticate yourself by logging into most common identity systems, so say Gmail or GitHub or GitLab or any of these other common identity providers, and you sign your code with that.